# Appbar/Toolbar not working

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making an android project by targetting api 13+. I need to have a appbar/toolbar instead of actionbar at the top of each activity I have in my app. I have tried searching over many blogs and SO itself but without any success.

I have created a base activity class and all my activities inherit from this class:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(tb);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("oh yeah");
    }
    ...
}
```

I have done the housekeeping stuff for the toolbar in this class and the following class is the activity which shows up when the app is launched:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // api level < 16 and > 16 have different
        // ways of removing the status bar
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        } else {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        // Create a new thread and delay for 3 sec
        // to handle the start of the main screen.
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
```

And this is the activity which is launched after the splash screen:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class MainScreen extends BaseActivity {

    private ImageButton btnLoyaltyForm;
    private ImageButton btnFeedbackForm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        btnLoyaltyForm = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLoyaltyForm);
        btnFeedbackForm = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFeedbackForm);

        btnLoyaltyForm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(), LoyaltyFormScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        btnFeedbackForm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(), FeedbackFormScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the XML for my appbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

android:id="@+id/app_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/actionbar_background_color"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Here is the XML for my MainScreen activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context="com.tarz.MainScreen">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <include
        android:id="@+id/appToolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnLoyaltyForm"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_form1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnFeedbackForm"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_form2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my app's manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tarz" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_base" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my colors.xml:

```
n="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="actionbar_background_color">#2d3135</color>
    <color name="actionbar_text_color">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="app_background_color">#f7f6f0</color>
    <color name="button_background_color">#2d3135</color>
    <color name="button_text_color">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Here is my styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:background">@color/app_background_color</item>
        <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>-->
        <!--<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionbar_background_color</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

When I run the app, the splash screen shows up then it crashes with the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

And

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

This is the log:

```
4059-4059/com.tarz E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tarz, PID: 4059
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tarz/com.tarz.MainScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.tarz.MainScreen.onCreate(MainScreen.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

How do I use the colors I have defined in my colors.xml so that my toolbar could have a different color, my app could have a different color and my toolbar's text could have a different color.

Also, menu on each activity would be different so the toolbar should adjust according to the activity, how could I do that also?

Please help, thanks. :)

**EDIT 1:**

After @Rod said to initialize toolbar after setting contentView, it cleared the NPE but then no toolbar is being shown:

[image]

This method is added at the top of the BaseActivity class:

```
public void initToolbar() {
    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("oh yeah");
}
```

and the onCreate now just have the super call. Also, the MainScreen class now have the `initToolbar();` called after `setContentView();` in `onCreate();` method.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin did not understood, what should I do?

Comment: You initialize the toolbar before you called the `setContentView` therefore it will always be NPE

Comment: So should I set the contentView before the super call? @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: Yes, or better approach would be removing initializing of toolbar from the parent class and add it after the contentView

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin but then I would have too add that initialization in every child class, right? Would not it be worse?

Comment: No just create a method with in the parent and call that method for every single child after the contentView

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin ok, let me try that.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin ok, that cleared the NPE. But now, no toolbar is shown. See the ss in my edit.

Comment: You really have a weird xml you need to be using a proper way of creating xml design with toolbar see example from one of google developer: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/tree/master/app/src/main/res/layout

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin what is different in my toolbar' XML?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109834/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-rod-algonquin).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I would point out:

1. You are not inflating a layout in your `onCreate()` in `BaseActivity`.
2. I think the official Toolbar tutorials are all using `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`.
3. You could define different Toolbar themes and apply them in different activities. More info [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).
4. Each activity has it's own toolbar, so you don't have to worry about supporting different menus for each activity. You simply inflate the menu XML for the activity in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

**EDIT 1: Inflating the appropriate layout in the base activity:**

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(getLayoutResId());
        final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(<your toolbar id>);
        // the rest of your logic
    }

    // This abstract method will provide a way for extending activities to give the id of their layout, so you can inflate it, before trying to set the toolbar
    @LayoutRes
    protected abstract getLayoutResId();
}
```

**EDIT 2: Customising the toolbar**
The Toolbar, like every other widget, can be customised using styles. To control the toolbar background colour, spacing, etc, you need to set a custom style to it. You can also change the toolbar title and subtitle appearance using the same mechanism. [Here](http://www.materialdoc.com/toolbars/) is a great link that shows all you need to know about creating and applying custom toolbar styles.

Comment: But I do not need to inflate in BaseActivity because this class does not have any layout instead the activities which inherit from this class have layouts and I set them in their respective classes, see in the MainScreen activity `onCreate()`.

Comment: Also can u help me in defining toolbar themes? Because I cant grasp the idea of what they write in the blogs. What should I do to integrate the toolbar in my app?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui The thing is you are trying to find the `Toolbar` in your `BaseActivity`, but it will only be available once you inflate the appropriate layout, that actually contains the toolbar instance. Check out the edit I made to my post.